# Question regarding multiprocessing speed gains in Python

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, slurm

I work on project where I'm processing several videos, which are each 1-2h long, and I have access to a high performance cluster using the SLURM Worload Manager. The main task of program is to track objects and evaluate some performance metric of the tracker, this all done using numpy and opencv commands and is running fine with about 30 FPS when running on just one video. However I would like to run the evaluation somewhat parallelized to save time. A simplified version of my code could look like this:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(videos):
        self.videos = videos
        self.object_tracker = ObjectTracker()

    def execute(self):
        jobs = []
        for video in self.videos:
            worker = VideoWorker(video=video, self.object_tracker)
            jobs.append(worker)
            worker.start()

        for j in jobs:
             j.join()

class VideoWorker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, video, object_tracker):
        self.video = video
        self.object_tracker = object_tracker

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video.path_to_video)

        while cap.isOpened():
            frame = cap.read()
            objects, tracks = self.object_tracker.process_frame(frame)

            """
            ... Further processing involving numpy and cv2 methods 
            """
            logging.info("Accuracy: %.2f" % accuracy")
```

I did not include the lines for switching between parallelized/serial processing, but thats just some if/else statements.

Ways I can run my code:

- Not parallelized, one video at a time, running on a node with up to 48 cores -> ~30 FPS
- Parallelized on one node (I tried both Process and Pool) with 48 cores -> ~5 FPS in each process/vid, I have 20 videos so the number of cores should not be the issue
- Parallelized by deploying my code on 20 nodes (one for each video, each process just opens/evaluates one video), limited to 1 core and 4GB mem per video/task, no multiprocessing in the actual code -> ~ 30 FPS in each task

I was expecting or hoping for similar performance when using multiprocessing on just one node since this would simplify stuff for me a bit (e.g. I could directly collect all results). My understanding was that multiprocessing spawns a new python process and assigns it to a free core and copies the necessary data in a memory space reserved for that freshly spawned process. Why is this so much slower when processing power does not seem to be the limit? Where is the time spent that prevents my evaluation loop from running faster when using multiprocessing?
I would be glad for some clarification!